# Spree - I'm able to see my tab in admin panel, but the authorization failed message flashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan, spree

I'm creating an extension for Spree. It allows multiple stores, so I added a panel in the admin area.

I also created a new role: store
And I created an AbilityDecorator as follows

```
module Spree
  class AbilityDecorator
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)

      if user.respond_to?(:has_spree_role?) && user.has_spree_role?('store')        
        can :admin, Store
      end
    end

  end
  Ability.register_ability(AbilityDecorator)
end
```

The problem is that I can access the admin area logged in with a store user. It only shows the Store tab. But i'm redirected to /admin/authorization_failed and the error flases.

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

I needed to add the following line to my decorator:

```
can [:admin, :index, :show], Order
```

Because the /admin is routed to orders_controller#index